# Magento 1.7.2 Problem cannot reindex product_flat_data even via ssh after dropping table please help

Tags: catalog, reindex

I have a problem when I try to reindex product flat data, the reindex of product_flat_data doesn't work. Message says "There was a problem with reindexing process." and  I have tried various solutions including:

- deleting var/locks files
- truncating table catalog_product_flat_1
- dropping catalog_product_flat_1
- using ssh to reindex ( php shell/indexer.php --reindexall )

The problem still occurs. I don't know what to do. Any help would be great.

---

### Edit

Here is the error message in exception.log

```
2014-04-04T13:48:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'mywebsitehere.#sql-34_10bf' (errno: 121)
Trace: #0 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2569): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#16 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#17 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.mywebsitehere.com/htdocs/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Comment: can you post the contents of var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log (if exists)

Comment: Any error message if you run indexer via ssh?

Comment: I edited my question with the error message inside exception. I get the same message in the ssh shell when trying to reindex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento should in theory log the exception thrown by this, see app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php line 133.

You could try dumping the exception straight to output if you wanted.

Comment: I edited my question with the message in exception.log

Comment: As Melvyn suggests - this could be a disk space issue.  It could also be a user permissions issue (your MySQL user).  Ensure that the MySQL user has all the permissions it requires to make a table on your specified database.

Comment: Thanks for your tips Douglas. I managed to finally make it work by deleting var/locks files again, deleting the table catalog_product_flat_1 again... Maybe not in that order. Hit the "reindex" button from my admin panel and the reindex worked. I have no clue why it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Clean out `/tmp/`, set `tmp_dir` in MySQL server configuration to something with plenty of space, restart MySQL server and try again.